# Growth rates of ‘sub-traces’ of matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, nonnegative-matrices

Consider an aperiodic, non-negative and non-zero $m\times m$ matrix $A$. Here aperiodic means that there exists an integer $n$ such that every entry of $A^n$ is strictly positive. By the Perron–Frobenius theorem $A$ has a strictly positive, real, simple maximal eigenvalue $\lambda >0$. In particular the trace of $A^n$ grows exponentially like $\lambda^n$, i.e.
$$
\operatorname{Tr}{(A^n)} = \lambda^n(1+O(\theta^n)) 
$$
for some $0 < \theta <1$. Let us write $P_n$ for the set of periodic $n$-long strings that are ‘allowed by $A$’:
$$P_n = \{I = i_1,\dotsc,i_n : i_j \in \{1,\dotsc, m\} \text{ with } i_1= i_n \text{ and } A_I >0\} $$
where each $i_j \in \{1,\dotsc,m\}$ denotes a row/column of $A$ and for each $I = i_1,\dotsc,i_n$ we write $A_I = A_{i_1, i_2}A_{i_2,i_3}\dotsm A_{i_{n-1},i_n}$ ($A_{i,j}$ is the $i,j$th entry of $A$). In this new notation,
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A^n) = \sum_{I \in P_n} A_I.
$$
Note that the growth rate of the cardinality of $P_n$ is purely exponential (indeed it is the growth rate if the trace of the matrix $\widetilde{A}$ where $\widetilde{A}_{i,j} = 1$ if $A_{i,j} >0$ and $\widetilde{A}_{i,j}=0$ otherwise).

My question is the following: if for each $n \ge 1$ we have a subset $Q_n \subset P_n$ such that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \#Q_n < \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \#P_n
$$
is it true that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \sum_{I \in Q_n} A_I < \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \sum_{I \in P_n} A_I = \lambda\ \ ?
$$
That is, if we looks at the contribution to the trace of $A^n$ coming from an ‘exponentially smaller’ subset of strings, do we see a drop in the exponential growth rate of $\operatorname{Tr}(A^n)$?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly the answer is negatif:
Take the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}100&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&1&1\end{array}\right)$.
Consider $Q_n=\{1^n\}$ and $P_n$
is the union of $Q_n$ with $\{2,3\}^n$.
Only $Q_n$ contributes asymptotically.

**Added:** In order to get your result you need a 'connectivity-condition': Every word in $Q_n$ can be realized as a subword of $u$
in $P_m\setminus Q_m$ for some $m>n$. This can be rephrased in terms of the directed graph $\Gamma$ with oriented edges $(i,j)$ if $A_{i,j}>0$. If for every $i,j$ there is an oriented path in $\Gamma$ which  starts at $i$ and ends at $j$ then your result holds. Otherwise you get
an invariant subspace generated by a subset of basis vectors ($\mathbb R(1,0,0)$ in the above example) which can contain the Frobenius-vector. This gives a counterexample.

Comment: Hi Roland. Thanks for your comment/answer. I'm assume that the matrix $A$ is aperiodic - that is there is some power of $A$, $A^n$ such that every entry of $A^n$ is strictly positive. Do you think my conclusion is true in this case?

Comment: Yes. You should state this definition of aperiodic (I interpreted it as $A^n\not= Id$ for all $n\geq 1$). Your condition is the same as the condition in my added remark.

Comment: Thanks and apologies for not being clear!

Comment: Do you have a proof/know a reference that proves the result?

Comment: You should rephrase your question more precisely and somebody will surely point you to relevant litterature. I am not sure that 'aperiodic' is a fortunate terminology. Give it another name and define it.